# python: merge two csv files

Tags: python, csv

I have a problem while I'm doing my assignment with python.
I'm new to python so I am a complete beginner.

Question: How can I merge two files below?

```
s555555,7
s333333,10
s666666,9
s111111,10
s999999,9
```

and

```
s111111,,,,,
s222222,,,,,
s333333,,,,,
s444444,,,,,
s555555,,,,,
s666666,,,,,
s777777,,,,,
```

After merging, it should look something like:

```
s111111,10,,,,
s222222,,,,,
s333333,10,,,,
s444444,,,,,
s555555,7,,,,
s666666,9,,,,
s777777,,,,,
s999999,9,,,,
```

Thanks for reading and any helps would be appreciated!!!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Don't ask people to do your homework. What are you gonna do in the exam? Ask the guy next to you?

Comment: Homework assignemnts are perfectly OK here http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Answer (score 4):

Here are the steps you can follow for one approach to the problem. In this I'll be using `FileA`, `FileB` and `Result` as the various filenames.

One way to approach the problem is to give each position in the file (each `,`) a number to reference it by, then you read the lines from `FileA`, then you know that after the first `,` you need to put the first line from `FileB` to build your result that you will write out to `Result`.

1. Open `FileA`. Ideally you should use the [`with statement`](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example) because it will automatically close the file when its done. Or you can use the normal `open()` call, but make sure you close the file after you are done.
2. Loop through each line of `FileA` and add it to a `list`. (Hint: you should use `split()`). Why a list? It makes it easier to refer to items by index as that's our plan.
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 for `FileB`, but store it in a different list variable.

Now the next part is to loop through the list of lines from `FileA`, match them with the list from `FileB`, to create a new line that you will write to the `Result` file. You can do this many ways, but a simple way is:

1. First create an empty list that will store your results (`final_lines = []`)
2. Loop through the list that has the lines for `FileA` in a `for` loop.

You should also keep in mind that not every line from `FileA` will have a corresponding line in `FileB`. For every first "bit" in `FileA`'s list, find the corresponding line in `FileB`'s list, and then get the next item by using the `index()`.  If you are keen you would have realized that the first item is always `0` and the next one is always `1`, so why not simply hard code the values? If you look at the assignment; there are multiple `,`s so it could be that at some point you have a fourth or fifth "column" that needs to be added. Teachers love to check for this stuff.

1. Use `append()` to add the items in the right order to `final_lines`.

Now that you have the list of lines ready, the last part is simple:

1. Open a new file (use `with` or `open`)
2. Loop through `final_lines`
3. Write each line out to the file (make sure you don't forget the end of line character).
4. Close the file.

If you have any specific questions - please ask.

Answer (score 2):

Not relating to python, but on linux:

```
sort -k1 c1.csv > sorted1
sort -k1 c2.csv > sorted2
join -t , -11 -21 -a 1 -a 2 sorted1 sorted2
```

Result:

```
s111111,10,,,,,
s222222,,,,,
s333333,10,,,,,
s444444,,,,,
s555555,7,,,,,
s666666,9,,,,,
s777777,,,,,
s999999,9
```

Comment: Nice one - but the objective here is to use Python as its homework.

Answer (score 1):

Make a dict using the first element as a primary key, and then merge the rows?

Something like this:

```
f1 = csv.reader(open('file1.csv', 'rb'))
f2 = csv.reader(open('file2.csv', 'rb'))

mydict = {}
for row in f1:
    mydict[row[0]] = row[1:]

for row in f2:
    mydict[row[0]] = mydict[row[0]].extend(row[1:])

fout = csv.write(open('out.txt','w'))
for k,v in mydict:
    fout.write([k]+v)
```

Comment: This has several (easily fixed!) problems.  (1) It leaks file refs.  (2) Any first element in f2 not in f1 will raise a KeyError when it's accessed in the second loop.  (3) `extend` is an in-place method and returns None, so that line won't work anyway.  (4) `write` is a typo for `writer`.  (5) `for k,v in mydict` won't work because iteration over `mydict` is over the keys, not over the key-value pairs.  Either `for k in mydict` or `for k,v in mydict.items():` or `for k,v in mydict.iteritems():` would work, but (6) this won't produce output in sorted order.

Comment: (7) It's not usually a good idea to provide code for homework questions. The idea is to _teach,_ not spoon-feed. Haven't we got enough incompetents in our industry already with encouraging more?