# Open csv files by using python

Tags: python, file, csv

I have a csv file looks like:

```
s555555,7
s333333,10
s666666,9
s111111,10
s999999,9
```

and when I open it in python it should look something like:

```
[[’s555555’, ’7’], [’s333333’, ’10’], [’s666666’, ’9’], [’s111111’, ’10’], [’s999999’, ’9’]]
```

What codes do i need to use for that?

Thanks and any helps would be so grateful!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [python: merge two csv files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980265/python-merge-two-csv-files)

Answer (score 4):

Check out the `csv` module. (http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)

Comment: Make an attempt with this module, and if you're still having trouble I'll help with your specific example.