# Merge two csv with join command

Tags: bash, csv, join, merge

I need to merge two csv files with different informations in the rows. I know that I can do something with the join command in bash (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980265/python-merge-two-csv-files/11980605#11980605)), but I don't know how to apply it to my data.

So here are examples of the two csv's:

CSV1:

```
Andre-Morange.trs;André Morange;2;no;M;58;yes;IDF;
Andre-Morange.trs;Sara enq;1;yes;F;63;yes;IDF / Nice;SARA
Anita Musso trs.trs;Anita Musso;1;no;F;46;yes;?;
Anita Musso trs.trs;Sarah enq;2;yes;F;63;yes;IDF / Nice;
Blanche_Duchemin_Jean_Pierre_Duchemin_Reine Ceret.trs;Blanche;4;no;F;25;yes;IDF;
Blanche_Duchemin_Jean_Pierre_Duchemin_Reine Ceret.trs;Jean-Pierre;2;no;M;60;yes;IDF;
Blanche_Duchemin_Jean_Pierre_Duchemin_Reine Ceret.trs;Reine;3;no;F;60;yes;IDF;
Blanche_Duchemin_Jean_Pierre_Duchemin_Reine Ceret.trs;Sarah enq;1;yes;F;63;yes;IDF / Nice;
Christophe_Andre_H_62_Marie_Anne_Andre_F_63_5e.trs;Christophe;3;no;M;61;yes;IDF;
Christophe_Andre_H_62_Marie_Anne_Andre_F_63_5e.trs;Dame + enqSarah;;;;;;;
Christophe_Andre_H_62_Marie_Anne_Andre_F_63_5e.trs;Dame + homme;4;;;;;;
Christophe_Andre_H_62_Marie_Anne_Andre_F_63_5e.trs;enqSarah;1;yes;F;63;yes;IDF / Nice;SARA
Christophe_Andre_H_62_Marie_Anne_Andre_F_63_5e.trs;Marie-Anne;2;no;F;62;yes;IDF;
```

CSV2:

```
Andre-Morange.trs;André Morange;2;
Andre-Morange.trs;Nasser;3;
Andre-Morange.trs;Sara enq;1;
Andre-Morange.trs;speaker#4;4;
Anita_Musso_trs.trs;Anita Musso;1;
Anita_Musso_trs.trs;Sarah enq;2;
Blanche_Duchemin_Jean_Pierre_Duchemin_Reine_Ceret.trs;Blanche;4;
Blanche_Duchemin_Jean_Pierre_Duchemin_Reine_Ceret.trs;Jean-Pierre;2;
Blanche_Duchemin_Jean_Pierre_Duchemin_Reine_Ceret.trs;Reine;3;
Blanche_Duchemin_Jean_Pierre_Duchemin_Reine_Ceret.trs;Sarah enq;1;
Christophe_Andre_H_62_Marie_Anne_Andre_F_63_5e.trs;Christophe;3;
Christophe_Andre_H_62_Marie_Anne_Andre_F_63_5e.trs;dame + enqSarah;5;
Christophe_Andre_H_62_Marie_Anne_Andre_F_63_5e.trs;dame + homme;4;
Christophe_Andre_H_62_Marie_Anne_Andre_F_63_5e.trs;enqSarah;1;
Christophe_Andre_H_62_Marie_Anne_Andre_F_63_5e.trs;Marie-Anne;2;
```

Here it is only a subpart of the two CSV's. What is important is that the first CSV has more columns but less lines than the second (CSV1 has 965 lines and 8 columns, while CSV2 has 1496 lines and 3 columns). However some of the lines in CSV2 are not present in CSV1. I want to merge the two files, in a way that in the end, I have all the lines from CSV2 added except the lines that were already present in CSV1.

I hope my question is not too confusing, I've been looking for a way to do this for several hours and I am myself confused!

Comment: you want to `join` based on the 1st column of file1 and file2..right?

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not clear. I want the output to be the same as CSV1 with all the lines contained in CSV2 added, except the lines of CSV2 that are already existant (with the same first three columns) in CSV1, since if they are in CSV1 they have more columns and thus infos I want to keep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not limited to using join, you can solve your problem with a short perl one-liner:

```
cat 1.csv 2.csv | perl -lne '$key = join ";", (split(/;/,$_))[0..2]; print $_ unless $seen{$key}++;'
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution works pretty well. I thought that a join command would have been easy, but using perl seems great for this problem!